# Extending Firebase Auth with user device authorization

Tags: firebase-authentication

Can anyone help clarify or provide any guidance on how we can allow our users to maintain a list of authorised devices from where they are allowed to login using Firebase Auth.

Is this a feature of 2fa?

Security is important and we want a user to control and approve logins from specific devices. Does FB Auth capture device information? Can I access this and use it? Do they create a unique fingerprint for each device?

I would like to implement something similar to Google accounts whereby I can revoke access from old devices or devices I dont recognise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> how we can allow our users to maintain a list of authorised devices from where they are allowed to login using Firebase Auth

Firebase Auth doesn't offer this sort of feature.

> Security is important and we want a user to control and approve logins from specific devices.

That's something you'll have to provide for yourself somehow.

> Does FB Auth capture device information?

No, it doesn't.  It allows anyone to call the REST API directly from anywhere that has an internet connection to sign in and get a token.